# How to compute the frame of a UIView before the transform?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform, cgsize

### Question

I have a `UIView` and I apply to it a `CGAffineTransform`. I would like to be able to know the frame of the view **if the transform had not be applied**.

I am looking for a (simple) solution that handles the case where the transform is the "zero-transform" (which is not invertible).

### My attempt

The following does not work for the "zero-transform", I guess.

```
CGRect result ;

CGAffineTransform transform = self.transform ;

result = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(self.frame, CGAffineTransformInvert(transform)) ;

return result ;
```

### Why?

I need to do this for an animation:

- initial settings: I set the `transform` "to 0". The view is inserted but the frames of all the elements do as if the view was not here.
- final settings: I compute the frames of all my elements, and this time I take into account the new view. I set its `transform` "to 1".

### Remarks

My transform is a scale transform.

Comment: CGRectApplyAffineTransform first parameter should be `self.frame` .
still instead of self.transform use `CGAffineTransformIdentity` ..

m unable to understand your question .
do u want to check if the `CGRectApplyAffineTransform ` is applied or not ? and if applied get the change in width and height ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`transform` does not affect `center` nor `bounds`.

So, you can calculate it by this simple code:

```
    CGPoint center = view.center;
    CGSize size = view.bounds.size;

    CGRect frameForTransformIdentity = CGRectMake(
        center.x - size.width / 2,
        center.y - size.height / 2,
        size.width,
        size.height
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1 version:**

```
extension UIView
{
    var frameWithoutTransform: CGRect
    {
        let center = self.center
        let size   = self.bounds.size

        return CGRect(x: center.x - size.width  / 2, 
                      y: center.y - size.height / 2,
                  width: size.width,
                 height: size.height)
    }
}
```