# Render UIImageView with transform as CALayer for video editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, quartz-core

I'm making an app that adds "stickers" to a Video playing in a background view. The stickers are added as imageView which responds to pan, pinch and rotate gestures, zoom and rotate are then applied to the UIImageview as transforms

To add the ImageViews to the video I must render them as CALayer as the following code

```
- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition size:(CGSize)videoSize {

    CGSize screenSize = self.view.frame.size;
    CGFloat scale = videoSize.width / screenSize.width; //get scale between video recorded and the screen used to edit

    //Creates parentLayer that contains videoLayer and each image layer

    for (UIImageView *imageView in [self.stickerContainer subviews]) {
        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        [layer setContents:(id)[imageView.image CGImage]];

        //Set layer frame
        CGRect imageFrame = imageView.frame;
        CGRect imageBounds = imageView.bounds;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(imageFrame.origin.x * scale, imageFrame.origin.y * scale, imageBounds.size.width * scale, imageBounds.size.height * scale);
        layer.frame = frame;

        //Second set transform
        CGAffineTransform transform = imageView.transform;
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(transform);

        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [parentLayer addSublayer:layer];
    }

    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
}
```

Basically create a layer with the same frame and transformation that the imageView has. But this creates weirds results with each gesture

1. Pan gesture results seems to has the Y-axis inverted (if I had the image at top-left it renders in bottom-left)
2. Rotate gesture results seems to have te b and c values inverted(from CGAffineTransform)
3. Zoom gesture results screw rendered origin point (since the layer origin point is the same.. maybe anchor point has to do something?)

Anyway.. any idea on why is this happening?.. If i had the image without any transformation and perfectly centered it appears as it should.

I based my code in the following [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) so the code to generate the new video is basically the same

Answer (score 5):

So I finally found a bit "hacky" solution.. I'll leave the code and explain it

```
- (void)applyVideoEffectsToComposition:(AVMutableVideoComposition *)composition videoSize:(CGSize)videoSize screenSize:(CGSize)screenSize stickersArray:(NSArray<UIImageView *>*)stickers{

    CGFloat videoScale = videoSize.width / screenSize.width; //get scale between video recorded and the screen used to edit

    CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
    parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
    //Add video layer first and then stickers
    [parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
    for (UIImageView *imageView in stickers) {
        CALayer *layer = [CALayer layer];
        [layer setContents:(id)[imageView.image CGImage]];

        //First set image size with bounds of original image and center (not affected by transform)
        CGSize imageSize   = imageView.bounds.size;
        CGPoint center = imageView.center;

       //Fix offset issue by getting bottom point of imageView to a screen size proportion
        CGFloat yOffset = (center.y + imageSize.height/2) / screenSize.height;
        yOffset = 1 - yOffset; // invert screen proportion
        CGFloat scaledOriginX = (center.x - imageSize.width/2)* videoScale;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(scaledOriginX, videoSize.height * yOffset, imageSize.width * videoScale , imageSize.height * videoScale);
        layer.frame = frame;


        //Apply transforms but to original imageView
        CGAffineTransform transform = imageView.transform;
        //Invert original transform b value with c value
        layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMake(transform.a, transform.c, transform.b, transform.d, 0, 0));



        [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
        [parentLayer addSublayer:layer];


    }

    composition.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool
                                 videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
}
```

Initially my code was flawed because I used the `imageView.frame` (`size` and `origin`), which both are affected by transform matrix, giving as result a weird frame for the `CALayer`. Instead I should have used imageView `bounds` and `center`, which are **not affected or changed by transform matrix** as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26192588/how-to-compute-the-frame-of-a-uiview-before-the-transform) shows

This fixes the zoom and origin point issues, however pan and rotation issues are still present

To fix pan gesture issues I had to manually "invert" the y Axis as this part of the code shows

```
    //Fix offset issue by getting bottom point of imageView to a screen size propotion
    CGFloat yOffset = (center.y + imageSize.height/2) / screenSize.height;
    yOffset = 1 - yOffset;
    CGFloat scaledOriginX = (center.x - imageSize.width/2)* videoScale;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(scaledOriginX, videoSize.height * yOffset, imageSize.width * videoScale , imageSize.height * videoScale);
    layer.frame = frame;
```

To fix inverted rotation I had to manually invert transform b and c values

```
 layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMake(transform.a, transform.c, transform.b, transform.d, 0, 0));
```

And that's basically it.. no idea why the rotation and pan issues occur but this should fix it. I really hope somebody has a better solution than mine and knows why this two last issues happen.

Comment: The issue with flipping the Y is that:
UIView's have 0,0 at top left
CALayer's have 0,0 at bottom left